# vectorize with a given function f which takes values on vector

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for asking a probably very basic question.
Suppose I have defined a function say f whose domain is p-dim vector and I have a list of p-dim vector say A. How can I vectorize my compution to get f(A[0]),f(A[1]),...,f(A[len(A)])?
For example:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return sum([x[i]*np.sin(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))])
A=[[i,i+1,i+2] for i in range(1000) ]
X=[f(A[i]) for i in range(len(A))]
```

How can I vectorize the computation above so that I get X faster?

Comment: Check out [numpy vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you wanted to vectorize generation of list `A` as well. In case you are concerned with your function `f(X)`, you might want to use Numpy's element-wise `multiply` method. Below is an example with benchmarking.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return sum([x[i]*np.sin(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))])

def f2(X):
    return np.multiply(X, np.sin(X))

start = timeit.default_timer()

A=[[i,i+1,i+2] for i in range(10000) ]
X=[f(A[i]) for i in range(len(A))]

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print(stop - start)


start = timeit.default_timer()

A=[[i,i+1,i+2] for i in range(1000) ]
X=[f2(A[i]) for i in range(len(A))]

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print(stop - start)
```

The output is:

```
0.16681260999631756

0.017789075556770784
```

meaning that `f2` is 10 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

In order to vectorize this fully you have to adapt the function `f` so that it works on the whole array `A`. In your example you want the sum of x*sin(x) across all rows in the array.

The multiplication and `sin` function works elementwise so doesn't need to be changed. But you have to specify to `np.sum` that you want to sum across rows; this is done by setting the 'axis=-1'.

```
def f_vec(x):                               
    return np.sum(x*np.sin(x), axis=-1)
```

You can pass the whole array `A` to this function and get `X` as before:

```
In [39]: X_vec = f_vec(A)

In [40]: np.all(X_vec == X)
Out[40]: True
```